# error while deploying with git to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to deploy myapp but I've encountered the following error:

[error](http://pastebin.com/8qfsgKwh)

Any idea? Where am I wrong?

Here my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.0'

gem 'pg'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

require 'execjs'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the line

`require 'execjs'`

to

`gem 'execjs'`